# VSCode Stops Connecting to MongoDB Server - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, visual-studio-code

I have a NodeJS application that uses **Mongoose** to store (small amounts of) data on my **MongoDB** database. I use **Nodemon** to automatically restart the server when any file in my project is saved. I type `npm start` in my VSCode terminal when I first open it, and usually leave it until I quit VSCode. After some times that I make the server restart automatically, my application stops connecting to MongoDB. It's been happening since I've started using Mongo and I still haven't found a solution to this. This is the error I get, after some time that the application is trying to connect to a Mongo database:

```
C:\Users\enric\Desktop\NodeJS Course\Section 14 - Sessions and Cookies\Online Shop Website\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:671
          throw error;
          ^

Error: Error connecting to db: queryTxt ETIMEOUT nodecoursecluster.lmj6z.mongodb.net
    at C:\Users\enric\Desktop\NodeJS Course\Section 14 - Sessions and Cookies\Online Shop Website\node_modules\connect-mongodb-session\index.js:78:17
    at C:\Users\enric\Desktop\NodeJS Course\Section 14 - Sessions and Cookies\Online Shop Website\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:668:9       
    at C:\Users\enric\Desktop\NodeJS Course\Section 14 - Sessions and Cookies\Online Shop Website\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:225:23
    at C:\Users\enric\Desktop\NodeJS Course\Section 14 - Sessions and Cookies\Online Shop Website\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:284:21
    at QueryReqWrap.callback (C:\Users\enric\Desktop\NodeJS Course\Section 14 - Sessions and Cookies\Online Shop Website\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:90:18)
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:203:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

(I'll definitely provide any additional needed information if anyone asks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the DNS to Google's 8888 8844. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9u5ULrRt3Y) video.